# I can highlight my checkboxes as checked but cannot uncheck them

Tags: javascript, dom

I am new to JS
I am trying to use vanilla JS to create a list of checkboxes, have them highlight when clicked and unhighlighted once clicked again.

I seem to be able to do the first part but not the second

```js
let check1 = document.getElementById('check1');
let check2 = document.getElementById('check2');
let check3 = document.getElementById('check3');

const checked = '//picsum.photos/25?c=1';
const unchecked = '//picsum.photos/25?c=0';

let box1 = 0;
let box2 = 0;
let box3 = 0;

function checkMe(check, box) {
    if (box == 0) {
        console.log(box)
        check.src = checked;
        box = 1
    } else if (box == 1) {
        console.log(box)
        check.src = unchecked;
        box = 0
    } else {
        console.log('broken');
    }
}
```

```html
<img id="check1" class="checkbox" src="//picsum.photos/25?c=0" onclick="checkMe(check1, box1);">
<img id="check2" class="checkbox" src="//picsum.photos/25?c=0" onclick="checkMe(check2, box2);">
<img id="check3" class="checkbox" src="//picsum.photos/25?c=0" onclick="checkMe(check3, box3);">
```

[How the checkboxes look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1cHp5.png)

I hoped that once I checked a box, the variable would be updated to the value of 1. Which indicated it is highlighted. Then when clicked again, since it has the value of 1 it would know that it needs to be unhighlighted

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're trying to track the "box status" individually by passing `box1`, but this is not a good idea in general. Since you already have a reference to to html element you can just set a attribute on that and based on toggle the state:

```js
function checkMe(check) {
  if (check.getAttribute('checked') === 'true') {
    check.setAttribute('checked', 'false');
    check.src = unchecked;
  } else {
    check.setAttribute('checked', 'true');
    check.src = checked;
  }
}
```

https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ex37lf